# Where are the message sent to when ack deadline exceeds

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

If multiple subscribers share the same pull subscription, when a message arrives at on subscriber, but it takes too long for the subscriber to ack the message, will the message be resent to the same subscriber or other subscribers? What if the subscriber dies before ack, which subscriber will the message be resent to?

Comment: My assumption would be that if you have a set of active subscribers, then if one of them gets the message but fails to ack it, then that message will be eligible to be retrieve by any subscriber ... which could be the same one that failed to ack the first time OR it could be any other one.

Answer (score 1):

Once a message that was delivered to a subscriber expires, it immediately becomes eligible for redelivery. Note that the message may or may not be delivered to the same subscriber binary; Cloud Pub/Sub gives no guarantees on “subscriber affinity/stickiness”.

In the same manner, if the subscriber binary dies before the ack can be sent, the message will be redelivered to another binary, after the ack expiration deadline.